# Solving for Ellipse Parameters given a radius and angle (Challenge 1)

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Given an ellipse centered on the origin in an x-y plane expressed as

$$\bigg(\frac{x}{a} \bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{y}{b} \bigg)^2 = 1$$

In polar coordinates with radius $R$ and angle = $\theta$, this can be expressed as:

$$R = \sqrt{\big(a^2 \cos ^2\theta\big)+\big(b^2 \sin ^2\theta\big)}$$

If we set a and b to be related as follows:

$a = 1 - \Delta$

$b = 1 + \Delta$

What is the simplest solution for $\Delta$ as a function of $R$ and $\theta$ as determined from the following relationship?

$$R = \sqrt{1 - 2\Delta \cos (2\theta)+ \Delta^2}$$

Comment: Solve it as a quadratic in $\Delta$?

Comment: Did you try generalized polar coordinates $x=ra\cos \theta, y=rb\sin \theta?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Delta^2- 2\Delta \cos(2\theta)+1-R^2=0\\\implies\displaystyle \Delta=\cos2\theta\pm\sqrt{\cos^22\theta+R^2-1}=\cos2\theta\pm\sqrt{R^2-\sin^22\theta}$

Comment: sorry that I changed my question on you!! If you have a solution to my expanded question I would be very appreciative!

Comment: @DanBoschen It's regarded poorly here to change the underlying question altogether after an answer has been posted.

Comment: @Travis I am so sorry- I will revert it and then repost my expanded question separately

Comment: I guess that was a steal...

Comment: No, good work @ShubhamJohri and thank you! Reposting with the additional items worked out fine.

Comment: @DanBoschen No worries, it's a perhaps nonobvious cultural thing to keep the site maximally usable (and to avoid annoying helpful answerers like Shubham). Welcome to math.se, by the way!