# Solving for Ellipse Parameters Given a radius and angle (Challenge 2)

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, quartics

Given an ellipse centered on the origin in an x-y plane expressed as

$$\bigg(\frac{x}{a} \bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{y}{b} \bigg)^2 = 1$$

In polar coordinates with radius $R$ and angle = $\theta$, this can be expressed as:

$$R = \sqrt{\big(a^2 cos^2\theta\big)+\big(b^2 sin^2\theta\big)}$$

If we set a and b to be related as follows:

$a = 1 - \Delta$

$b = 1 + \Delta$

The solution for $\Delta$ as a function of $R$ and $\theta$ is determined from

$$R = \sqrt{1 - 2\Delta cos(2\theta)+ \Delta^2}$$

Which as given in [Solving for Ellipse Parameters given a radius and angle (Challenge 1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035317/solving-for-ellipse-parameters-given-a-radius-and-angle/3035328#3035328)
has the simplest solution as $$\Delta = cos(2\theta) \pm \sqrt{R^2-sin^2(2\theta)}$$

I am trying to similarly solve for $\Delta$ given a modified ellipse with the following relationship:

$$R = (1-\Delta)\sqrt{1 - 2\Delta cos(2\theta)+ \Delta^2}$$

What is the simplest form of $\Delta$ given $R$ and $\theta$ from the above equation?

If a simple relationship does not exist, then an approximation will be acceptable given that I can limit $\Delta$ to be $0.9<\Delta<1$

(Note this is related to my answer at this link on the signal processing site where I had to find the root of the equation to solve but am hoping for a simple closed form equation: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54006/computation-of-parameter-filter-to-match-a-given-frequency-response/54008#54008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squaring both sides gives
$$R^2 = (1 - \Delta)^2 (\Delta^2 - 2 \Delta \cos 2 \theta + 1) .$$
This is a quartic equation in $\Delta$, so [there *is* a closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation) in terms of $R, \theta$, but [it's too large to reproduce here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots%20of%20Delta%5E4%20-%202*Delta%5E3*b%20-%202*Delta%5E3%20%2B%204*Delta%5E2*b%20%2B%202*Delta%5E2%20-%20R%5E2%20-%202*Delta*b%20-%202*Delta%20%2B%201): For general values of $\theta, R$ there won't be a simple form, and given the content of the linked post, the numerical approximations you've already been using are probably the most useful. If you're interested in limiting cases, say, $R \ll 1$ or $R \gg 1$, one can analyze the above equation to produce good approximate solutions for $\Delta$.

**Edit** If we have the additional condition that $R \ll 1$, then substituting gives $\Delta \approx 1$. To get a next-order approximation, we can set $\Delta = 1 + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \approx 0$ (this is close to the condition specified in the edit to the original question), giving $$\epsilon^4 + 4 \sin^2 \theta \, \epsilon^3 + 4 \sin^2 \theta \, \epsilon^2 = R^2 .$$ Provided that $\sin \theta$ is not too close to $0$, the $\epsilon^2$ term on the left dominates the others, giving $$\epsilon \approx \pm \frac{R}{2} \csc \theta,$$
so
$$\Delta \approx 1 \pm \frac{R}{2} \csc \theta .$$

On the domain $\frac{9}{10} < \Delta < 1$ of interest, this is a robust approximation:
[image]

From innermost to outermost, the red curves are the graphs of the solution functions $\Delta(\theta)$ for $R = \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{32}, \frac{1}{64}, \frac{1}{128}$, and the blue curves are the graphs of the above approximations.

On the other hand, for very small $R$, say, $R < \frac{1}{64}$, it's possible for to have $\frac{9}{10} < \Delta < 1$ but $\sin \theta$ small enough that the above approximation becomes poor: In the limit $\sin \theta \to 0$, the $\epsilon^4$ term dominates, giving a zeroth-order approximation $\Delta \approx 1 - \sqrt{R}$. Computing to second order in $\sin \theta$ gives the approximation $$\Delta \approx 1 - \sqrt{R} + \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}\right) \sin^2 \theta .$$

[image]

This plot for $R = \frac{1}{256}$ is typical for $R < \frac{1}{100}$; the green curve is the small-angle approximation. (NB the expanded scale of the horizontal axis.)

Comment: Thank you Travis. I can limit $Delta$ to be greater than 0.9 and less then 1 if that helps get to an approximate solution. What approach do you suggest to find an approximate in that case? (Or should I post that as another question?)

Comment: If we know a priori that $\frac{9}{10} < \Delta < 1$, one strategy is to change variables to $s = 1 - Delta$, so that we're working in the domain $s \ll 1$. Then, the equation becomes $R^2 = 2 (1 - \cos 2 \theta) s^2 - 2(1 - \cos 2 \theta) s^3 + s^4$. Provided that $\cos 2 \theta$ isn't too close to $1$, the $s^2$ term dominates, and ignoring the other terms gives $s \approx \pm \frac{1}{2} R \csc \theta$ (so, the condition on $\Delta$ implies that $R$ must have been small in the first place).

Comment: Excellent- May I update my question to allow for an approximation within my bound for $\Delta$ so that you can add this to your answer?

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to update my answer. In general, most people won't object addition of specifying/ info/follow-up questions to a question within reason. The issue I mentioned on the other question is more about altering the original question altogether, especially when it renders inapplicable existing answers.

Comment: And yes R is quite small. if this means anything, I am showing how the peak gain of a filter varies with choice of frequency where the frequency is given as an angle between 0 and $2\pi$. The peak gain is typically large, and R is the inverse of this gain.

Comment: This takes me back to my analog electronics course as an undergrad! I've added an explanation how to take into the condition $R \ll 1$, which in particular implies $\Delta \approx 1$.

Comment: Super- yes this would be similar to poles for an analog filter on a s plane. In this case it is a digital filter so maps to polar coordinates on a z plane; the vertical imaginary $j\omega$ axis becomes the unit circle. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad to help---I hope you found it useful!

Comment: If you decide to post separately a follow-up question, feel free to link it in another comment to my answer, and I'll take a look and see what I can do.

Comment: Works great! I got 0.9696 using your estimate for my example case from the Signal Processing Stack Exchange link, where $\theta$ was 0.377 and R=1/44.67. The answer I got by solving for the real root of the equation was 0.9691.

Comment: Great graph! Wish I could upvote again. You took out your $1-1/sqrt(R)$ approximation as the angle approach $0$ (and $\pi$ due to symmetry). Did you find an error with that? I know the true answer (not an approximation) when the angle is $0$  is $R=(1-\Delta)^2$, so therefore in this case $\Delta = 1 \pm \sqrt{R}$. Agree?

Comment: Which interestingly means somewhere in the small angle region, where both approximations still match, and due to small angle $sin(\theta)=\theta$ it means that $\sqrt{R} \approx 2\theta$

Comment: (And as such must be a reasonable approximation where the lines in your graph are vertical, all those lines would then approach $\theta = \sqrt{R}/2$ as the angle gets smaller if I worked that out correctly above). But I can' t tell exactly if that does match-- you listed 4 values for $R$ yet there are 5 graphs in the plot.

Comment: Thanks! No, there wasn't an error, but after graphing I found that for most values of $R$ displayed (say, $R \geq \frac{1}{64}$) the domain where the small-angle approximation applies well has $\Delta \leq \frac{9}{10}$, which was outside the range of interest. If you're interested in the setting where that's not so (so, small angles and $R$ very small, say, $R < \frac{1}{64}$) I'm happy to readd that approximation and perhaps a plot. (The fifth $R$ value is $R = \frac{1}{128}$ and corresponds to the outermost pair of curves---I'd just omitted it accidentally.)

Comment: (And yes, I agree that for $\theta = 0$ we have $\Delta = 1 \pm \sqrt{R}$.)

Comment: Yes in those regions it just means a much smaller R is required, yet it does converge so is doable. Do you see any utility to the $R \approx 2 \theta$? Since $\theta$ can go to $0$ and $R$ does not at $\theta = 0$ then it implies there is a region where that is generally valid, I just don't know how big of a region and if that is helpful (or if I made a mistake coming to that conclusion).

Comment: (Actually since my goal is to solve for $\Delta$ there is little utility in that interesting relationship between $R$ and $\theta$ for small $\theta$ except to show how sensitive $\Delta$ is to variations in $\theta$ as well evidenced by your graphic.)

Comment: I added in a comment (and a plot) about the case of small $\theta$ and small $R$.

Comment: Love it! Just trying to understand the final plot: I take it the red and blue are the same as the first plot (actual vs approx using csc), is the green the result of the final function you wrote with the $sin^\theta$ term? Is there a (simple) way to combine the two (transition) for a complete approximation at all angles?

Comment: It appears that $(1-1/\sqrt{R})sin(N \theta)$ may approximate it closer since the green curve quickly diverges from the truth.

Comment: My naive stab at a unified approximation: $1-\sqrt{R} - \frac{\theta}{\theta-R}(\frac{R}{2}csc(\theta)- \sqrt{R})$.  (And for my prior comment above I was referring to the second term in your approximation with the first term as you had it, so basically a sine instead of $sin^2$ and then if needed stretching out the angle with a factor of N.)